# How to install XDM on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tar

I'm trying to install the latest version of xdm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from the official website http://xdman.sourceforge.net/ ..

I managed to extract it, but i couldn't insall it! .. Any help? [here's what's inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuEAG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't install it, just run the 'xdm' executable in the folder and you are good to go. You can also move it to a global location, you can run these commands from your Desktop

```
sudo cp xdm /usr/share
sudo ln -s /usr/share/xdm/xdm /usr/bin/xdm
```

This way, you can run it just by typing `xdm` in the terminal.

Comment: Does that mean  i have to run it from the folder everytime i reboot the system?

Comment: Not exactly, you have to run it from the folder everytime you want to use the program.